# Kafka consumer - what's the relation of consumer processes and threads with topic partitions

Tags: java, multithreading, distributed-computing, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have been working with Kafka lately and have bit of confusion regarding the consumers under a consumer group. The center of the confusion is whether to implement consumers as processes or threads. For this question, assume I am using the high level consumer.

Let's consider a scenario that I have experimented with. In my topic there are 2 partitions (for simplicity let's assume replication factor is just 1). I created a consumer (`ConsumerConnector`) process `consumer1` with group `group1`, then created a topic count map of size 2 and then spawned 2 consumer threads `consumer1_thread1` and `consumer1_thread2` under that process. It looks like `consumer1_thread1` is consuming partition `0` and `consumer1_thread2` is consuming partition `1`. Is this behaviour always deterministic? Below is the code snippet. Class `TestConsumer` is my consumer thread class.

```
    ...
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(2));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    int threadNumber = 0;
    for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
        executor.submit(new TestConsumer(stream, threadNumber));
        threadNumber++;
    }
    ...
```

Now, let's consider another scenario (which I haven't experimented but am curious) where I start 2 consumer processes `consumer1` and `consumer2` both having the same group `group1` and each of them is a single threaded process. Now my questions are:

1. How will the two independent consumer processes (under the same group nevertheless) be related to the partitions in this case ? How is it different from the above single process multi-thread scenario?
2. In general, how are consumer threads or processes mapped / related to partitions in the topic?
3. The Kafka documentation does say that each consumer under a consumer group will consume one partition. However, does that refer to a consumer thread (like my above code example) or independent consumer processes?
4. Is there any subtle thing I am missing here regarding implementing consumers as processes vs threads? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A consumer group can have multiple consumer instances running (multiple process with the same `group-id`). While consuming **each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer instance in the group**.

E.g. if your topic contains 2 partitions and you start a consumer group `group-A` with 2 consumer instances then each one of them will be consuming messages from a particular partition of the topic.

If you start the same 2 consumer with different group id `group-A` & `group-B` then the message from both partitions of the topic will be broadcast to each one of them. So in that case the consumer instance running under `group-A` will have messages from both the partitions of the topic, and same is true for `group-B` as well.

Read more on this on their [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theconsumer)

**EDIT** : Based on your comment which says,

> ***I was wondering what is the effective difference between having 2 consumer threads under the same process as opposed to 2 consumer processes (group being the same in both cases)***

The consumer `group-id` is same/global across the cluster. Suppose you have started process-one with 2 threads and then spawn another process (may be in a different machine) with the same groupId having 2 more threads then kafka will add these 2 new threads to consume messages from the topic. So eventually there will be 4 threads responsible for consuming from the same topic. Kafka will then trigger a re-balance to re-assign partitions to threads, so it could happen that for a particular partition which was being consumed by thread `T1 of process P1`may be allocated to be consumed by thread `T2 of process P2`. The below few lines are taken from the wiki page

> When a new process is started with the same Consumer Group name, Kafka will add that processes' threads to the set of threads available to consume the Topic and trigger a 're-balance'. During this re-balance Kafka will assign available partitions to available threads, possibly moving a partition to another process. If you have a mixture of old and new business logic, it is possible that some messages go to the old logic.

Comment: I understand what you said. However, my main concern in my original question was thread vs process. I was wondering what is the effective difference between having 2 consumer threads under the same process as opposed to 2 consumer processes (group being the same in both cases)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That really answers my curiosity. In the meantime, I have done some further experiments with multiple processes and saw the rebalancing happening :).

Answer (score 1):

The main design decision for opting for multiple consumer group instances with the same id vs a single consumer group instance is resiliency. For example if you have a single consumer with two threads then if this machine goes down you loose all consumers. If you have two separate consumer groups with the same id, each on different hosts then they can survive failure. Ideally each consumer group should have two threads in the above, therefore if one host goes down the other consumer group uses its dormant thread to take up the other partition. Indeed it is always desirable to have more threads than partitions to cover this factor.

1. You can run each consumer group on different hosts. With a single consumer group for a given name/id it will only ever run on a single host as it manages all its threads in a single runtime environment.
2. Kafka has an algorithm to determine which threads/consumer groups reads the various topic partitions. Kafka tries to evenly distribute these in a resilient fashion. When a consumer group fails, it enables other threads in other groups to read the given partition.
3. Refers to a single thread in the consumer group. If there are more threads than partitions then some of them will just remain dormant until other threads fail to offer resiliancy.
4. The preference relates to resilience. So with multiple consumer groups setup with the same id I can run on multiple hosts making my application tolerant to failure.

Comment: There are many incorrect things in your answer. First, you can run multiple consumer hosts with a single consumer group. Offsets are tracked on the group level, so groups are used to avoid threads within the group stepping on each others' toes. I.e. if you set up 2 hosts with 2 distinct groups to ingest the same topic, you'll end up with double the amount of messages.

Comment: The second thing is that Kafka does not have an algorithm to determine when threads fail, you need to respawn the failed thread manually, otherwise that partition will not get consumed, even for high-level, group-based consumer. I tested this exact thing with 4 partitions and 8 threads and the partition belonging to the failed thread just stays un-consumed (i.e. its offset does not move until the thread is respawned).

Comment: So if you have 4 partitions and spawn 8 consumer threads, 4 threads will do nothing at all. On the other hand, if you spawn 2 threads, each will consume from 2 partitions.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make clarify what was meant. If you run multiple consumer groups with the same id/name then the work is spread amoung multiple JVMs - I've tested this and it does happen. Also kafka does have an algorithm to determine when threads fail, again I've tested this by killing a thread in a consumer group then watching another thread in another consumer group with the same name take up the partition.

Comment: My advice would be to create multiple consumer groups with the same id and watch kafka distribute the load over the consumer groups. The key thing is to have the same name/id. This is how you increase consumer resiliance to failure. If all your consumer groups for a given consumer group name were on the same host and it failed then your application would stop reading from Kafka.

Comment: In short: My answer was about multiple consumer groups with the same name, not multiple consumer groups with different names. The later will re-read the messages as each consumer groups has its own offsets, while the former will spread the partitions among the various groups, all consuming the messages once.

Comment: Interesting, I'll test that. You could further improve you answer by excluding your comment that says "With a single consumer group you can only ever run on a single host as it manages all its threads in a single runtime environment."

Comment: May I ask where did you find the information regarding this fault-tolerant behavior caused by having multiple consumer threads with same name/id?

Comment: Ok have changed that comment to hopefully make more sense. Regarding the fault-tolerant behavior for multiple consumers I basically tested it myself. I ran two consumer groups, each with the same id/name. I could see each group consuming and shared the load from a 4 parition topic. I then killed one consumer group and saw the other consumer group take up the load (ie it read all topics so long as it is started with enough threads).

Comment: For example both groups had 4 threads so could read all the partitions on its own but when there were two groups only 2 thread for each group were active. It was only when one died, that the other consumer group actived its other dormant threads - ie it was fault-tolerant and kept reading all the partitions for a given topic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed answer from @user2720864, but I think the *re-allocation* case @user2720864 mentioned in the answer is not correct => one partition cannot be consumed by two consumers.

When there are more consumers (compared to the partitions), each partition will be exclusively allocated to one consumer only while the *leftover* consumers will stay lazy only until some working consumers being dead or being removed from the group.

Based on the [Kafka Consumers document:](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers)

> The way consumption is implemented in Kafka is by dividing up the partitions in the log over the consumer instances so that each instance is the **exclusive consumer** of a "fair share" of partitions at any point in time. This process of maintaining membership in the group is handled by the Kafka protocol dynamically. If new instances join the group they will take over some partitions from other members of the group; if an instance dies, its partitions will be distributed to the remaining instances.

And also its [API specification](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) at "Consumer Groups and Topic Subscriptions" section:

> This is achieved by balancing the partitions between all members in the consumer group so that each partition is assigned to **exactly one** consumer in the group.