# Does producer and consumer need to specify partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We are planning to have a producer (Java rest api)
And consumer (Java client ) running in multiple machines and all the consumers belong to same consumer group.

1) In this case if I do not specify partition during producer publishing messages in which Kafka writes into random/default  partition ...

2) While consumer retrieving messages ,if I don't mention partition I'd and just pass the topic name ..and commit the offset to Kafka server..

Is this a good approach if I have one consumer group???

3)do I need to have Kafka rest proxy ,as per my understanding it's not required as I'm using Java client ..please correct me if I'm wrong ...please lemme know what benefit I'll get if I have to use Kafka rest proxy here....

Answer (score 3):

From the producer perspective, if the record doesn't have any key the producer will insert the records in a round-robin way between the partitions in a topic.
From the consumer perspective, you don't need to specify the partition if any consumer can handle any record from that topic, if you want actually you don't  even have to commit the offset, the client can do it for you with `auto.commit.enable=true`.

Yes, if you have 1 consumer group you can add multiple consumers and balance the load between the group (this depends on the number of consumers in the group and the number of partitions).

3) You don't need kafka rest proxy when using the java client, besides (If I am not mistaken) the kafka rest proxy has a dependency on the schema registry, so you would have to run both.

Comment: 1) in my case I have to manual commit because I want to commit only when the message is processed successfully...auto commit will commit once consumer reads the message...correct me if I'm wrong ...2) can I mention the partitions upfront in Kafka based on the number of consumers I have ..if yes how 3) can I use multiple threads in each consumer to read and process messages so that I can process more messages than single message per each consumer ...in this case is there any issue when setting offset???

Comment: in a consumer group each consumer has its own partitions, hence commiting the offset should always be safe, you need to create 1 thread per consumer, and not share the consumer between the threads. Just commit manually sync or async and disable the autocommit.

Comment: Would like to know why we should not create multiple threads in a consumer ..anyways Kafka treats even thread as consumer and runs rebalancing for the partitions ..I mean if I have 4 partitions and 2 consumers ..and if I have 2 threads in each consumer ..so total 4 threads and Kafka assigns each partition to each thread ....please correct me if I'm wrong..the reason why I'm insisting multiple threads is I can process 4 messages even I have two consumers ...please lemme know if there is any bottleneck in this approach..cos if I want to process 20 messages at a time I need to create 20 consumers

Comment: the reason is that the new consumer is single-threaded, if you want to know more about it, you can read this blog http://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0.9-consumer-client

Comment: what im saying is when i say consumer its an application and will create multiple threads to create multiple Kafkaconsumer objects and everything runs in a seperate thread...please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470720/kafka-consumer-whats-the-relation-of-consumer-processes-and-threads-with-topi

Comment: You asked me: "why we should not create multiple threads in a consumer" thats why I am pointing you to that documentation. 
Yes, what you can create 1 thread per consumer and run multiple threads that ok because the consumer will be single-threaded inside that thread and will need to have a different consumer client id than the rest of the threads.

Comment: So where I'm little bit concerned is in this case Will be there any issue with partition allotment when one of the thread broken..if not please direct me to any sample where the multithreaded approach is handled deligently ..that would be really helpful!!

Comment: If one of the consumers in a consumer group dies, the partitions assigned to this consumer will be redistributed between the live consumers so all partitions are always been consumed as long as you have at least 1 consumer alive in the consumer group.

Comment: So here suppose I create 3 threads in a single consumer (consumer application) each thread will be treated as consumer ??? And rebalancing happens between them if one thread is broken ??

Comment: Rebalancing happens with consumers in a consumer group, please read the documentation http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html